# ring signature with embedded data

Tags: encryption, signature

As part of Spontaneous Anonymous Group (SAG) signatures of say 16 participants, the prover generates fake random responses for 15 elements and a real response at some secret index. I want to hijack this scheme and instead of putting random data in the 15 elements, I want to fill it up with data encrypted with some secret key. Everyone can still be able to verify the signature, but only the entity having the secret key can also decrypt the data. But the problem is, in order to decrypt the data, the entity has to know the secret index (so as to avoid using data at that index during decryption) and thereby will also know the real signer, which I want to avoid.

Do you see any way I can achieve this? The specific entity should be able to decrypt the data but also not know the secret index.

Comment: It seems that the short-lived signature and designated-verifiers signature schemes may be able to assist you in reaching your objective.